# Does Twitter make Twitter outage data available?

Tags: twitter, dataset, twitterapi-python, twitter-api-v2

I'm looking to find Twitter outage data, a dataset that can tell you when, where, and for how long Twitter becomes offline or difficult to use/access. Does Twitter make this information available somewhere, maybe through its APIs?

Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

No, there is no Twitter API for that. I suspect you could use something like Down Detector but I don’t know what historical data it has available (and we are in the realms of recommending software, which is off topic for Stack Overflow)